# Selecting every alternate group of n columns - NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to select every nth group of n columns in a numpy array. It means that I want the first n columns, not the n next columns, the n next columns, not the n next columns  etc.

For example, with the following array and `n=2`:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

I would like to get:

```
[[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10],
 [11, 12, 15, 16, 19, 20]]
```

And with `n=3`:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9],
 [11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19]]
```

With `n=1` we can simply use the syntax `arr[:,::2]`, but is there something similar for `n>1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`modulus`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html) to create ramps starting from `0` until `2n` and then select the first `n` from each such ramp. Thus, for each ramp, we would have first `n` as `True` and rest as `False`, to give us a boolean array covering the entire length of the array. Then, we simply use [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) along the columns to select the valid columns for the final output. Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
arr[:,np.mod(np.arange(arr.shape[-1]),2*n)<n]
```

Step by step code runs to give a better idea -

```
In [43]: arr
Out[43]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])

In [44]: n = 3

In [45]: np.mod(np.arange(arr.shape[-1]),2*n)
Out[45]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3])

In [46]: np.mod(np.arange(arr.shape[-1]),2*n)<n
Out[46]: array([ True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,False])

In [47]: arr[:,np.mod(np.arange(arr.shape[-1]),2*n)<n]
Out[47]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  7,  8,  9],
       [11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Sample runs across various `n` -

```
In [29]: arr
Out[29]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]])

In [30]: n = 1

In [31]: arr[:,np.mod(np.arange(arr.shape[-1]),2*n)<n]
Out[31]: 
array([[ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9],
       [11, 13, 15, 17, 19]])

In [32]: n = 2

In [33]: arr[:,np.mod(np.arange(arr.shape[-1]),2*n)<n]
Out[33]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 15, 16, 19, 20]])

In [34]: n = 3

In [35]: arr[:,np.mod(np.arange(arr.shape[-1]),2*n)<n]
Out[35]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  7,  8,  9],
       [11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a little question, is there a particular reason why you are using `arr.shape[-1]` and not `arr.shape[1]`?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMartin I guess I had a generic ndarray in mind, so that it would work for arrays of any dimensions for selecting columns, which would always be the last dimension.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this, and pretty much every other way of achieving the desired result, creates a new array (copies the data) rather than a view of the original array.

Comment: @Divakar Ok, and thank you for your detailed answer!